# Error 500 on Phabricator installation on Ubuntu (Apache2 / php5-fpm / Mysql)

Tags: apache, ubuntu, php, phabricator

I'm trying to install Phabricator on my server. I followed the documentation here : https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/installation_guide/

On the step :

> Now, navigate to whichever subdomain you set up. You should see
>   instructions to continue setup.

I get an error "500" :

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

Here is the logs :

```
[Sun Apr 13 23:40:43 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Sun Apr 13 23:40:43 2014] [debug] core.c(3112): [client 127.0.0.1] r->uri = /php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/ 
[Sun Apr 13 23:40:43 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/ 
[Sun Apr 13 23:40:43 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/ 
[Sun Apr 13 23:40:43 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/ 
[Sun Apr 13 23:40:43 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/  
[Sun Apr 13 23:40:43 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/  
[Sun Apr 13 23:40:43 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/  
[Sun Apr 13 23:40:43 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/  
[Sun Apr 13 23:40:43 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri  = /php5-fcgi/php5-fcgi/  
[Sun Apr 13 23:40:43 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /php5-fcgi/  
[Sun Apr 13 23:40:43 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /
```

Here is the vhost configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerAdmin cont....fr
        ServerName p....fr
        ServerAlias proj....fr

        DocumentRoot /home/tea(....)icator/webroot

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/(....)ricator/webroot>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
       Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-project.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel debug

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my apache2/conf.d/php5-fpm.conf :

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
        Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
        Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
        FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -appConnTimeout 10 -idle-timeout 250 -socket /tmp/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
</IfModule>
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to my friend, I quickly found a solution.
I simply added :

> RewriteRule ^/php5-fcgi -  [L]

To my vhost configuration :

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -    [L,QSA]  
RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^/php5-fcgi     -                       [L]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]
```

Thanks.