# Unable to configure phabricator on apache 2.4/redhat 7.0

Tags: apache, phabricator

I am trying to configure phabricator on redhat machine on which WHM and cpanel configured.

I am using my .htaccess file to setup configuration.

This is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -    [L,QSA]  
RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]

Require all granted
```

and this is what i am getting on my apache2.4 error logs

```
 AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace
```

I tried everything which i found on google.
Please help

Comment: Does everything you found on Google include http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048827/error-500-on-phabricator-installation-on-ubuntu-apache2-php5-fpm-mysql ? If not, the information in that question indicates that turning on debug logging should show you which URL is being redirected, so a similar solution for the affected URL may work.

Comment: I found the solution on a link...and it is now working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just modified my .htaccess by replacing $1 with /$1 which  works for me

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -    [L,QSA]  
RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=/$1  [B,L,QSA]

Require all granted
```